# Using SUMIF on a range of columns or SUMPRODUCT to ignore text items

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a range with various text and numbers in them. I wish to total the numbers based on the identifying first column.

I have tried

`=SUMIF(A1:A20,"John",B1:E20)`

which only returns the first columns number. I've also tried

`=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A20="John")*(B1:E20))`

but as there is text in column C, it returns #VALUE!.

A |  B  | C |  D |  E

John  |   5     |  Wine |    2   |    7

Sean  |   6     |  Beer |    5   |    2

I want all of the numeric values in columns B-E to be totalled together when "John" is in column A

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an array formula solution - use Ctrl, Shift and Enter to confirm:

```
=SUM(IF(A1:A20="John",IF(ISNUMBER(B1:E20),B1:E20)))
```

If you just want to exclude column C you could use this non-array formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A20="John")*(B1:B20))+SUMPRODUCT((A1:A20="John")*(D1:E20))
```

Alternatively, perhaps move C so it's not in the middle of your numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula:

```
=IF(A1="John", SUMPRODUCT(--(ISNUMBER(B1:E1)),B1:E1), "")
```

and drag down to get sum on each row.

Comment: I think you not taking into account it's a larger matrix expanding over multiple rows.

Comment: Yep, I saw the solution above and suggest if he needs sum of each row. Thanks anyway